# CakePHP 2.X: Prevent saveAssociated() from creating a record if it already exists

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.7, cakephp-2.x

I have the following models:

```
class Useragent extends AppModel {

    public $validate = array(
        'useragent' => array(
            'unique' => array(
                'rule' => 'isUnique',
            ),
        )
    );

    public $hasMany = array(
        'LoggedActions'
    );
}
```

and

```
class LoggedAction extends AppModel {

    public $belongsTo = array(
        'Useragent' => array(
            'className' => 'Useragent',
        )
    }
}
```

The purpose of these two models is to keep track of the IP address and user agent of the site visitors. I want the tables to be normalized, as I don't want every row to repeat the long user agent string.

To track a visitor, the code would look like:

```
    $data=array(
        'LoggedAction'=>array(
            'ip_address' => 3232235521, //INET_ATON format
        ),
        'Useragent'=>array(
            'useragent'=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'
        )
    );

    $this->LoggedAction->saveAssociated($data);
```

I want the `Useragent` model to **ignore the save if the user agent is already present in the `useragents` table** (based solely on the field `Useragent.useragent`, not on `Useragent.id` which is unknown when performing the save).

I know I can implement this on the controller, by dealing with `Useragent` first and then with `LoggedAction`. However, I would like the model to take care this transparently.

- Returning false in `Useragent::beforeSave()` if the record exists does not work, as nothing is saved.
- Replacing `Useragent['id']` in `Useragent::beforeSave()` with the `id` from the existing record fetched from the db, will not validate. Removing the validation rule will throw `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'`.

An option is to **override the `Useragent::save()`** method, so that it ignores the save operation, but sets the `Useragent->id` to the `id` of the record fetched from the db and returns the array (like a normal save would do), but not sure if this will break other functionality.

Another option is to write a method called something like `LoggedAction::saveWithUseragent()`, which will implement the described functionality. But as I said, I would like the model `Useragent` to take care of this as transparently as possible.

Is there a better way of implementing this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I finally chose to override `Useragent::save()`.

This is how my `Useragent` class now looks:

```
class Useragent extends AppModel
{

    public $displayField = 'useragent';

    public $hasMany = array(
        'LoggedActions'
    );


    public function save($data = null, $validate = true, $fieldList = array()){

        if ($useragent=$this->findByUseragent($data['useragent'])){
            $this->id=$useragent[$this->alias]['id'];
            return($useragent);
        }
        return parent::save($data,$validate,$fieldList);
    }
}
```

No problems so far.

The same approach could be used for tags associated with other models.